# Different colors for outputs in Python

Tags: python, colors, output, instance

I have a question that is asking me to print different colors for different instances. For example, for instance #1 print in blue color and for instance #2 print green color.

Please find the code I did below:

```
#function to display the output
def displayCustomer(self):
    customer=""
    if customer==customer1:
        print("\033[94m" "First Name: ", self.getfirstname(), "\nLast Name: ", self.getlastname(), "\nGender: ", self.getgender(), "\nPhone Number: ", self.getphone_number(), "\nHome Address: ", self.getaddress())
    else:
        print('\033[92m' "First Name: ", self.getfirstname(), "\nLast Name: ", self.getlastname(), "\nGender: ",self.getgender(), "\nPhone Number: ", self.getphone_number(), "\nHome Address: ", self.getaddress())
```

It doe's seem to work properly.

Comment: Could you be more specific in what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-colors-python-terminal] 
    (This is a website that uses Colorama as an example it also has sample code)

Comment: Dear Fried, the question is asking me to get an input from the user. His name, gender, address, etc. More than one user, so for each user I want the output be in different colors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`termcolor` library](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/) like the following:

```
from termcolor import colored

for i, x in enumerate(["test1", "test2"]):
    if i == 0:
        print(colored('hello {:}'.format(x), 'blue'))
    else:
        print(colored('hello {:}'.format(x), 'green'))
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSI sequences will only work if you are in DOS based-windows or Windows 10 with VT100 emulation, and in OS X. So you should make a look at [Termcolor module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor)